# Blur.js gives weird placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blur

im using blur.js to blur a div's background inside a parent div which im using as the source.

This is the visual;

```
+-----------------+
|     -------     |
|     | div |     |
|     ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯     |
+-----------------+
```

My parent div has some CSS to position the background properly;

```
background-image: url("../img/jumbo.jpg");
background-size:cover;
background-position: center center fixed;
```

But the div on the inside does not copy the same background position as its parent.

I have tried adding the CSS to the class of the inside div, but this does not help me achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle or something that can reproduce the problem? Also did you look through their [issue list](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Blur.js/issues)?

Comment: @anpsmn I have made this fiddle, but it cannot recreate the effect, the website where it currently testing on: www.anytime.glr-imd.nl